# Group into 2 week periods

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table (called 'transactions') that contains customer transaction data. Each row contains a customer number and the date of a transaction. I need to display the total number of transactions each customer has had in a defined 2 week period. For all customers the 2 week period starts on 22/8/2016. So I need to know how many transactions each customer has had in a rolling 2 week period from 22/8/2106 onwards.

I need the return to display the customer number, the start date of each 2 week period and the number of transactions in that 2 week period.

As an example, the sample data below:

```
╔══════════╦════════════╗
║ Customer ║ Date       ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 1234     ║ 22/08/2016 ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 1234     ║ 23/08/2016 ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 1234     ║ 24/08/2016 ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 1234     ║ 3/09/2016  ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 1234     ║ 3/09/2016  ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 5678     ║ 26/08/2016 ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 5678     ║ 27/08/2016 ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 5678     ║ 28/08/2016 ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 5678     ║ 29/08/2016 ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 5678     ║ 30/08/2016 ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 5678     ║ 30/08/2016 ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 5678     ║ 30/08/2016 ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 5678     ║ 6/09/2016  ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 5678     ║ 6/09/2016  ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 5678     ║ 7/09/2016  ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 5678     ║ 8/09/2016  ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ 5678     ║ 12/09/2016 ║
╚══════════╩════════════╝
```

Needs to return this:

```
╔══════════╦═════════════════╦═══════╗
║ Customer ║ Week Start Date ║ Count ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════╬═══════╣
║ 1234     ║ 22/08/2016      ║ 5     ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════╬═══════╣
║ 5678     ║ 22/08/2016      ║ 7     ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════╬═══════╣
║ 5678     ║ 5/09/2016       ║ 5     ║
╚══════════╩═════════════════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: Please provide sample fiddle to repro the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon close inspection, your expected results are a bit unexpected to me, because you are listing customer ids along with an aggregate of the number of customers.  Typically, you would just be expecting a total number of customers for each two week period, which is what my query below should generate.

```
SELECT t.Customer,
       DATEADD(day, (t.twoWeekPeriod-1)*14 + 3, '2016-01-01') AS [Week Start Date],
       t.customerCount AS [Count]
FROM
(
    SELECT Customer,
           FLOOR(DATEPART(week, DATEADD(day, -3, Date)) / 2) AS twoWeekPeriod,
           COUNT(*) AS customerCount
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Date >= '2016-08-22'
    GROUP BY Customer,
             FLOOR(DATEPART(week, DATEADD(day, -3, Date)) / 2)
) t
```

**Explanation:**

- SQL Server begins the first "week" of the year on January 1st.  Since your starting date in `22-Aug-2016`, the first week (and all subsequent weeks) began on Friday.  Since your starting date is a Monday, I roll back all dates by 3 days to get everything aligned.
- Having rolled back `22-Aug-2016` by 3 days, it is now the start of the 34th week of the year.  This means that week 35 should also be a part of this first two week group.
- `FLOOR(DATEPART(week, DATEADD(day, -3, Date)) / 2)` groups together sets of 14 days in a single two week period

**Update:**

As you pointed out, the above query won't work as intended if your data spans more than one calendar year.  In this case, you can form two weeks groups using the number of days alone, with `2016-08-22` (or any other date you want) serving as the first two week period:

```
SELECT t.Customer,
       DATEADD(day, (t.twoWeekPeriod)*14, '2016-08-22') AS [Week Start Date],
       t.customerCount AS [Count]
FROM
(
    SELECT Customer,
           FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day, '2016-08-22', Date) / 14) AS twoWeekPeriod,
           COUNT(*) AS customerCount
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE Date >= '2016-08-22'
    GROUP BY Customer,
             FLOOR(DATEDIFF(day, '2016-08-22', Date) / 14)
) t
```

Comment: But I need to know the number of transactions for each customer, grouped into 2 weekly periods. My table contains other fields (such as transaction amount) but they are irrelevant for this issue. I only included the fields that are relevant to my question.

Comment: @user2430812 Then you can just add `Customer` to the `GROUP BY` list, q.v. my updated response.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you

Comment: Although, this only gives me data for one year. How can I extend this indefinitely? Or alternatively, if I want to look back to, for example, the start of 2014 onwards?

Comment: @user2430812 I updated my answer again.  I think you can just add the year to the `GROUP BY` list and also select it out.  My query should work for _any_ date after `2016-08-22` with this modification, as far as I know.

Comment: Hmm. I now need to run this from the beginning of 2013 (1/1/2013) but with my 'anchor date' of Monday 07/1/2013. And it needs to run from that date onwards. This is giving me weird data:

Comment: SELECT t.Customer, 
DATEADD(day, (t.twoWeekPeriod-1)*14 + 6, '2013-01-01') AS [Week Start Date],t.Year,    
t.customerCount AS [Count]
FROM
(
    SELECT Customer, 
    FLOOR(DATEPART(week, DATEADD(day, -6, date)) / 2) AS twoWeekPeriod,
    YEAR(date) as 'Year', COUNT(*) AS customerCount
    FROM transactions
    where date > '2013-01-07'
    GROUP BY Customer, FLOOR(DATEPART(week, DATEADD(day, -6, date)) / 2) ,YEAR(date)
) t

Comment: I'm not sure I have a clean solution for dealing with year boundaries.  But then again, you did not mention this in your original question.

Comment: Yeah I know. Sorry. Thanks anyway though, you've got me a lot further down the track.

Comment: That's it! Thank you again.